# Need to convert datetime containg '/' to '-' format

Tags: c#, datetime-format

Need to convert `dtApprovedAt = DateTime(10/23/2018 2:33:18 AM)` to `10-23-2018 2:33` format.

Tried using the below code

```
DateTime.ParseExact(dtApprovedAt.ToString(), "M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", 
CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm")].ToString())
```

But it is throwing `System.Format` exception

Comment: smal 'ml' is minute and big 'M' is month, therefore **mm**-dd-yyyy hh:mm should be **MM**-dd-yyyy hh:mm

Comment: And I suspect you want `HH` instead of `hh` in the output format, unless you really don't want to be able to tell the difference between 2am and 2pm.

Comment: You should not write a one-liner, this is bad practice, since you made 3 mistakes in that one line. Just split it up into multiple lines. Readability is key. Compiler does not care about single-line code vs. 4 lines of code.
This code works: 
`DateTime parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dtApprovedAt.ToString(), "M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            String parsedStr = parsedDate.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm").ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(parsedStr);`
see `https://rextester.com/XZANCF15575`

Comment: Also note that calling `ToString()` on a string is redundant.

Comment: What's the type of `dtApprovedAt`, and why are you messing around with `DateTime` formats anyway? In c#, [`DateTime` has no display format](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/12/19/for-the-1024-time-datetime-has-no-format/), and you only need to use format when displaying it to a human.

Comment: This code worked for me :                                                                                                                                                  

     
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("03/14/2012 01:00:00 PM", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            var dtString = dt.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm");
            DateTime dtNew = DateTime.ParseExact(dtString, "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Answer (score -1):

The problem, is that `dtApprovedAt.ToString()` is not producing in `"M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt"` format.

if you have already a DateTime object, all you need to do is:

```
dtApprovedAt.ToString("mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm")
```

Comment: I know, I preferred still use the one in the question, so OP know where it came from. He will read here and understand the correct format.